# If the difference between two sequences is bigger than 30, deduct bigger sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm having a hard time trying to make a query that gets a lot of numbers, a sequence of numbers, and if the difference between two of them is bigger than 30, then the sequence resets from this number. So, I have the following table, which has another column other than the number one, which should be maintained intact:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| Id | Number | Status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 | OK     |
|  2 |      1 | Failed |
|  3 |      2 | Failed |
|  4 |      3 | OK     |
|  5 |      4 | OK     |
|  6 |     36 | Failed |
|  7 |     39 | OK     |
|  8 |     47 | OK     |
|  9 |     80 | Failed |
| 10 |    110 | Failed |
| 11 |    111 | OK     |
| 12 |    150 | Failed |
| 13 |    165 | OK     |
+----+--------+--------+
```

It should turn it into this one:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| Id | Number | Status |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 | OK     |
|  2 |      1 | Failed |
|  3 |      2 | Failed |
|  4 |      3 | OK     |
|  5 |      4 | OK     |
|  6 |      1 | Failed |
|  7 |      4 | OK     |
|  8 |     12 | OK     |
|  9 |      1 | Failed |
| 10 |      1 | Failed |
| 11 |      2 | OK     |
| 12 |      1 | Failed |
| 13 |     16 | OK     |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Thanks for your attention, I will be available to clear any doubt regarding my problem! :)

EDIT: Sample of this table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded5af

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do but you need one more column here to use for ordering. Is this just for a select statement or are you trying to update this table? With your results there is nothing left to maintain the order. What would really help is you could post ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com would be a good place for that.

Comment: @SeanLange In fact, I have an ordering column, i will add this on an edit.
The data is confidential and dense, so I simplified it focusing on my problem.

Comment: Understand the data sensitivity. Not a big deal. What version of sql server are you using? And can you convert this into a sqlfiddle so we can work on the problem directly without having to convert your sample into a working example?

Comment: SQL server 2014! I will try to do so! Thanks :)

Comment: Use the LAG() function with a CASE statement

Comment: Need to include a sample of how to handle a gap less then 30

Comment: @SeanLange http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8282c

Comment: @Frisbee You're right, adding

Comment: Start with gaps and islands.  If someone can do this without a cursor they have my up vote.

Comment: Your sqlfiddle is in mysql but you said you are using sql2014. Which one is correct?

Comment: sql2014, I'm so sorry.

Comment: @Rabbit instead a comment put that in an answer because, well... that is the answer. ;)

Comment: @Rabbit Should you answer the question with this argument, please, show me an example at least because I don't have the knowledge you presented.

Comment: @RicardoC I would if I had more time to write something up. And I will if someone doesn't beat me to the punch before I have some time to devote to this.

Comment: @SeanLange http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9322e

Comment: @Rabbit Thanks for the tip, anyway, I'm trying to research its usage.

Comment: @LucasGarcia it is just a simple read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: Quick question.. is the Number field always increasing?.. can the next id in your table 10 be less than id 9 which is 80?

Comment: @RicardoC I'm into this, trying to turn it into an answer :)

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes, always increasing

Comment: Can you update your expected results to match the sqlfiddle?

Comment: @SeanLange Of course.

Comment: @SeanLange http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded5af, this should be compatible with this question's table.

Comment: I'll be heading home right now, so I won't be able to answer questions... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this test case:

```
declare @data table (id int identity, Number int, Status varchar(20));
insert @data(number, status) values
     ( 1,'OK')
    ,( 1,'Failed')
    ,( 2,'Failed')
    ,( 3,'OK')
    ,( 4,'OK')
    ,( 4,'OK')      -- to be deleted, ensures IDs are not sequential
    ,(36,'Failed')  -- to be deleted, ensures IDs are not sequential
    ,(36,'Failed')
    ,(39,'OK')
    ,(47,'OK')
    ,(80,'Failed')
,(110,'Failed')
,(111,'OK')
,(150,'Failed')
,(165,'OK')
;

delete @data where id between 6 and 7;
```

This SQL:

```
with renumbered as (
    select rn = row_number() over (order by id), data.*
    from @data data
),
paired as (
    select
        this.*,
        startNewGroup = case when this.number - prev.number >= 30 
                               or prev.id is null then 1 else 0 end
    from renumbered this
    left join renumbered prev on prev.rn = this.rn -1
),
groups as (
    select Id,Number, GroupNo = Number from paired where startNewGroup = 1
)
select
     Id
    ,Number = 1 + Number - (
                    select top 1 GroupNo 
                    from groups where groups.id <= paired.id 
                    order by GroupNo desc)
    ,status
from paired
;
```

yields as desired:

```
Id          Number      status
----------- ----------- --------------------
1           1           OK
2           1           Failed
3           2           Failed
4           3           OK
5           4           OK
8           1           Failed
9           4           OK
10          12          OK
11          1           Failed
12          1           Failed
13          2           OK
14          1           Failed
15          16          OK
```

**Update**:  using the new LAG() function allows somewhat simpler SQL without a self-join early on:

```
with renumbered as (
    select
         data.*
        ,gap = number - lag(number, 1) over (order by number)
    from @data data
),
paired as (
    select
        *,
        startNewGroup = case when gap >= 30 or gap is null then 1 else 0 end
    from renumbered 
),
groups as (
    select Id,Number, GroupNo = Number from paired where startNewGroup = 1
)
select
     Id
    ,Number = 1 + Number - ( select top 1 GroupNo 
                             from groups 
                             where groups.id <= paired.id 
                             order by GroupNo desc
                           )
    ,status
from paired
;
```

Comment: This does not work to produce the desired output. After a gap of > 30 the next row is NOT the next sequential value.

Comment: @SeanLange: With the `> 30` changed to `>= 30` it now does.

Comment: @SeanLange; Note that I deliberately reproduced real life, and created a gap in the ID's to test that the functionality worked even when that occurs; **which it eventually will**.  If you want the ID values to match deliberately, skip the two exra data ines and the DELETE that removes them.

Comment: @SeanLange: Run my SQL against my test case if you don't believe me. Then run it against your test case if you still don't believe me.

Comment: With your edit of >= 30 it does work now. :) If I have some time I will try to put something together that isn't using a recursive cte but this certainly works. Well done.

Comment: @SeanLange: It's NOT a recursive CTE; merely a nested CTE. There is no use of any CTE within the same CTE.  You can easily rewrite this as nested subqueries, at a loss in readability If you have a large data set, put ***paired*** into a temp table, so that it is not calculated twice, to improve performance.

Comment: What is `GroupNo` for? It's the same as `Number`. I removed it, replaced with `Number` and got the same results.

Comment: @Andrew: Good catch; it's a zombie from an earlier (more complicated) implementation.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

I don't deserve answer but I think this is even shorter

```
with gapped as 
(   select id, number, gap = number - lag(number, 1) over (order by id)
    from @data data
),
select Id, status
       ReNumber = Number + 1 - isnull( (select top 1 gapped.Number 
                                          from gapped 
                                         where gapped.id <= data.id 
                                           and gap >= 30 
                                         order by gapped.id desc), 1)  
from @data data;
```

Comment: I'm using this version, and giving you and @Andrew my sincere 'thanks' for the concern with simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply Pieter Geerkens's answer slightly simplified. I removed some intermediate results and columns:

```
with renumbered as (
    select data.*, gap = number - lag(number, 1) over (order by number)
    from @data data
),
paired as (
    select *
    from renumbered 
    where gap >= 30 or gap is null
)

select Id, Number = 1 + Number - (select top 1 Number 
                             from paired 
                             where paired.id <= renumbered.id 
                             order by Number desc)
    , status
from renumbered;
```

It should have been a comment, but it's too long for that and wouldn't be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make another cte before this and use row_number instead of ID to join the recursive cte,  if your ID's are not in sequential order

```
WITH cte AS 
(   SELECT 
        Id, [Number], [Status],
        0 AS Diff,
        [Number] AS [NewNumber]
    FROM
        Table1
    WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        t1.Id, t1.[Number], t1.[Status],
        CASE WHEN t1.[Number] - cte.[Number] >= 30 THEN t1.Number - 1 ELSE Diff END,
        CASE WHEN t1.[Number] - cte.[Number] >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE t1.[Number] - Diff END
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN cte ON cte.Id + 1 = t1.Id
)
SELECT Id, [NewNumber], [Status] 
FROM cte
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9322e/8)

Here is another SQL Fiddle with an example of what you would do if the ID is not sequential..

[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded5af/1)

In case sql fiddle stops working

```
--Order table to make sure there is a sequence to follow
WITH OrderedSequence AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) RnId,
        Id,
        [Number],
        [Status]
    FROM 
        Sequence
),
RecursiveCte AS 
(   SELECT 
        Id, [Number], [Status],
        0 AS Diff,
        [Number] AS [NewNumber],
        RnId
    FROM
        OrderedSequence
    WHERE Id = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        t1.Id, t1.[Number], t1.[Status],
        CASE WHEN t1.[Number] - cte.[Number] >= 30 THEN t1.Number - 1 ELSE Diff END,
        CASE WHEN t1.[Number] - cte.[Number] >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE t1.[Number] - Diff END,
        t1.RnId      
    FROM OrderedSequence t1
    JOIN RecursiveCte cte ON cte.RnId + 1 = t1.RnId
)
SELECT Id, [NewNumber], [Status] 
FROM RecursiveCte
```

Comment: This does not work to produce the desired output. After a gap of > 30 the next row is NOT the next sequential value.

Comment: you sure about that? it matches his expected results? @SeanLange

Comment: Yes. Something is wrong with fiddle. Your link above keeps crashing right now.

Comment: @SeanLange link works ok for me..  try the second one.. SQL fiddle is always giving me fits

Comment: I know what you mean. Neat tool but it does seem to have lots of problems.

Comment: This has the best query plan. If that sort of thing matters to anyone

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize the queries here, since it took 1h20m to process my data. I had it down to 30s after some further research.

```
WITH AuxTable AS 
(   SELECT
        id, 
        number,
        status,

        relevantId = CASE WHEN 
            number = 1 OR 
            ((number - LAG(number, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id)) > 29)
        THEN id
        ELSE NULL
        END,

        deduct = CASE WHEN 
            ((number - LAG(number, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id)) > 29)
        THEN number - 1
        ELSE 0
        END

    FROM @data data
)
,AuxTable2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        number,
        status,
        AT.deduct, 

        MAX(AT.relevantId) OVER (ORDER BY AT.id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS lastRelevantId

    FROM AuxTable AT
)

    SELECT 
        id, 
        number,
        status,   

        number - MAX(deduct) OVER(PARTITION BY lastRelevantId ORDER BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS ReNumber,

    FROM AuxTable2
```

I think this runs faster, but it's not shorter.